# Shouldn't Magic Missile be a Divination Spell instead of Evocation?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, spellcasting

Don't take me wrong, but in all editions I've seen so far, *Magic Missile* is a spell that launches darts or orbs of pure magical force (thus, it's an Evocation Spell). Inside its descriptions, it says that the spell "always hits" their targets, unless the target is protected by a *shield* spell.

How does that work?  How the spell can know where the target is, and more accurately, how can it find any path at all that can reach and strike down a target?
Is it because the caster commands the spell telepathically somehow?  Does the spell guess where it should move in order to reach their target at each feet/square?

If the answer in your head is something like "the caster passes instructions to the spell beforehand, so it can maneuver itself on the environment, until it reaches the target" then tell me, how can the spell take its time to redirect itself in case the target attempts to evade it?

I can't speak much for earlier editions (as I never played them before), but if we're talking about 5e, any character can set a reaction saying "If that guy casts magic missile, and I'm a target, I attempt to avoid it using a reaction by moving 2 feet forward". It won't be able to avoid it because if the description of the spell is correct, the MM will follow the target until it hits.

Why is doesn't that work?
Why MM always hits the target, unless it casts "Shield" as a way to block it?

---

In my theory, it's because MM should be a Divination Spell, not an Evocation one. If its main feature (to always hit) makes the spell to be able to "think", "see/sense things around" or "communicate telepathically with the caster in realtime", then shouldn't it be a Divination spell?

Now, my question is not about changing the mechanics, or trying to break the rules, or trying to make Divination casters op. I'm just trying to figure out the correct flavour of the spell.  Why is it Evocation spell at all. Just because it's pure magical force being unleashed? Or am I misinterpreting what the spell does in most editions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be about developer intent.

Comment: Voting to close as it is both opinion based and about dev intent.

Comment: @CarlHR Asking about developer intent is not off topic. I voted to close this because it is opinion based, as it instead seems to be asking us what we think the developers should have done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the thing is... Dungeons & Dragons waffles a lot on what the spell schools *actually are*. Sometimes they’re ineffable facts of the multiverse, inherent parts of these spells. Other times, they’re just traditional divisions of academia and traditional categorization of spells and effects between them. Either due to a specific historical arcane university, or just hand waved as “I dunno, everyone’s always done it that way.”

In other words, they don’t really necessarily make a whole lot of narrative sense, because their narrative sense isn’t totally consistent. Plenty of spells have switched schools between editions, too (e.g. healing spells have been necromancy, conjuration, and evocation at different points in D&D’s publication history). And—aside from a very brief experiment in 3.5e’s *Player’s Handbook II*—every spell has to be assigned to exactly one (1) spell school. If you can identify parts of the spell that seem to be one school and other parts that seem to be another school, too bad: pick just one.

So does *magic missile* have some divinatory effects? Arguably, yes; but it’s still evocation because its primary effect is a blast of energy. (In more metagame terms, it deals direct damage, which is basically never something divinations do.) *Alarm* is abjuration, even though a **major** component of that spell is the ability to detect those entering the warded area. *Magic missile* is much more evocation-y than *alarm* is abjuration-y, for my money.

If you really wanted to imagine *magic missile* as purely evocation, though, you probably could, if you imagine the missiles themselves as being made of energy that you’ve somehow “attuned” to your target such that it is attracted as if magnetic. Nothing in the spell’s description hints at any of that, but then it doesn’t really hint, specifically, at it having a minor divination component.

But I can’t think of any analogous argument for *alarm*; that spell definitely seems like it needs to have some divination in it. And some other choices don’t even make that much sense: I can see *alarm* as primarily abjuration with some divination thrown in, but why is *mage armor* a conjuration *at all* in 3.5e? Almost everyone thinks it should be abjuration, but even evocation would make more sense than conjuration does. Wizards of the Coast themselves seemingly forgot it’s a conjuration sometimes, as *Complete Mage*’s example abjurant champion shows. But *Player’s Handbook* has it as a conjuration, and despite being subject to numerous errata, FAQ entries, and reprints, it’s stayed a conjuration throughout the edition. It’s pretty hard to argue it’s unintentional.

On the subject of intentions, though, we **also** have spells that seem like straight typos. *Sign* has as its descriptive text “The tea leaves burst into flames between your fingers, and for a brief moment you see the future in the billowing smoke,” but for some reason it’s an enchantment. It’s an enchantment in both *Miniatures Handbook* and *Spell Compendium*, but nonetheless, I’m calling that one a typo; the name and description of that spell could not be more divination if they tried. So don’t read too much into spell schools.

Comment: As an historical note, the original design for magic missile was to require a to hit roll. Gary Gygax was convinced by one of the other early TSR emplyoees to always make it hit, because back then 1st level wizards had just one 1st level spell per day, and it really would have sucked to miss with it.

Comment: My intention that led me to ask this question was that the spell primary effect shouldnt be damage. Its a collateral effect caused when the spell collides with the target. In my head, the spell would have to firstly know where the target would be, as if accurately reading the future, then move to the target, then deal damage. But according to nobody the hobgoblin's note, it's just some second effect somebody though it would be cool, and everyone rolled with that. Now I know that MM was indeed intended to be an evocation spell, and that effect is meant to be secondary. I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlHR I mean... my point isn’t so much that it’s “right” that the primary effect is damage and “wrong” that the primary effect is seeking—it’s more that _spell schools are decided quasi-arbitrarily by the authors_. The only “sense” they have to make is in the author’s head (that they can convince editors of). Reading more into it than that is an exercise in frustration. Why does 3.5e put *mage armor* in Conjuration? Both Abjuration and Evocation would make far more sense, but it is. Even the authors forgot it (see _Complete Mage_’s example abjurant champion), but it is what the books say.

Comment: I mean, there's a *lot* of spells that seem to straddle the school lines -- spells that have elements of multiple schools or could be argued several different ways.  *Symbol* alone seems to have aspects of abjuration (it protects an area), divination (it can identify creatures' characteristics), and depending on which effect you select, any of evocation, necromancy, or enchantment. Arbitrary is a good word for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because it's pure magical force being unleashed.

That is the spell's *raison d'être*.  Without that, there's no point.  Anything else is in support of unleashing the magical force and getting it where it needs to go.